# Server to server realtime communication

Tags: web, websocket

I'm looking to have 2 remote servers communicate in real time. Websockets looks to be a choice however all the docs I've been finding say Websockets is intended for web browser client to server communication. Is there a competing technology that would better server this purpose?

My intent is to send realtime JSON data back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the competitor here might be JMS or any other messaging framework.

But you can use WebSockets for this if you want, it should do just as well, especially if you don't need any complex subscriber mechanism. WebSocket protocol is considered to be pretty "raw" compared to others, you can send or receive text or binary messages and thats basically it(*).

If you use any Java EE 7 compatible app server, it should have JSR 356 support built in. I work on [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net), which is used in [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net) and WebLogic and it also capable of running on plain [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net) (lightweight) container.

(*) there is concept of encoders/decoders in JSR 356, which might help you with initial (en/de)coding of your message; there are plenty of use cases with other new Java EE 7 spec - JSONP, which might make your life easier even more.

Answer (score 1):

[Socket.io](http://socket.io) has a server to server node.js package called [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client). It enumerates a client for servers.

Simple usage from one of our projects:

```
// remote server connecting to server1.io:4321
var clientio  = require('socket.io-client');

var client = clientio.connect("http://server1.io:4321", {
  'force new connection': true,
  'reconnect': true,
  'reconnection delay': 1000,
  'max reconnection attempts': 10
});

client.on('connect', function(socket) {
  console.log("connected");
});
```